# Out Of Dialog NOTIFY message in SIP

Tags: c++, sip

It is possible to send Out Of Dialog NOTIFY message? 
I am working on a PBX and SIP phones are connected to it. I need to send the NOTFIY message to the phone on some change in PBX. I know that the phones must subscibe to the PBX and PBX can send the NOTIFY messsage, which is in dialog message.

What I need is the OUT Of Dialog NOTIFY message to be phone. Phones has already code to understand the OOD NOTIFY.
I know that there is implicit subscription for methods like REFER. Is there some thing like that, so that i can send the OOD NOTIFY without subscription to phones?

Answer (score 2):

There's no standardised way to send a NOTIFY without a requisite subscription (I have seen cases where NOTIFY requests are used as a NAT keep-alive mechanism without a subscription but that's a hack by some naughty ATAs).

This [thread](https://lists.cs.columbia.edu/pipermail/sip-implementors/2004-April/006386.html) on the SIP implementors provides a good alternative to unsolicited NOTIFY's which is to use the [PUBLISH](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc3903.txt) request.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include "pjsip_event_notification.h"
#include <pjsip.h>
#include <pjsip_ua.h>
#include <pjlib-util.h>
#include <pjlib.h>
#include <pjlib.h>
#include <pjsua.h>
#include <pjsua-lib/pjsua_internal.h>

static EventCallBack* registeredCallbackObject = NULL;

extern "C" {

  pj_bool_t on_rx_response_wrapper(pjsip_rx_data *rdata){
          registeredCallbackObject->on_rx_response(rdata);
          return PJ_FALSE;
 }

  pj_bool_t on_rx_request_wrapper(pjsip_rx_data *rdata){
          registeredCallbackObject->on_rx_request(rdata);
          return PJ_FALSE;
  }


  /* The module instance. */
  static pjsip_module mod_event_handler =
  {
      NULL, NULL,             /* prev, next.      */
      { (char*)"mod-reg-event", 12 },  /* Name.        */
      -1,                 /* Id           */
      PJSIP_MOD_PRIORITY_TSX_LAYER - 1,  /* Priority         */
      NULL,               /* load()       */
      NULL,               /* start()      */
      NULL,               /* stop()       */
      NULL,               /* unload()     */
      &on_rx_response_wrapper,               /* on_rx_request()  */
      &on_rx_response_wrapper,               /* on_rx_response() */
      NULL,               /* on_tx_request.   */
      NULL,               /* on_tx_response() */
      NULL,               /* on_tsx_state()   */

  };


  PJ_DECL(pj_status_t) event_callback_init() {
      return pjsip_endpt_register_module(pjsua_get_pjsip_endpt(),
                          &mod_event_handler);
  }

 void setEventCallbackObject(EventCallBack* eventCallBack){
         registeredCallbackObject=eventCallBack;
 }


}
```

the h file for the same pjsip_event_notification.h

```
#include <pj/config_site.h>
#include <pjsua-lib/pjsua.h>

class EventCallBack {

public:
        virtual ~EventCallBack() {}
        virtual void on_rx_response(pjsip_rx_data *rdata){
 // Target Call Back for Notify message
        }

        virtual void on_rx_request(pjsip_rx_data *rdata){

        }



};
extern "C" {
pj_status_t event_callback_init();

void setEventCallbackObject(EventCallBack* eventCallBack);
}
```